# Speed up startup time of a SpringBootTest with SpringRunner

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am looking for a way to minimize startup time of a `SpringBootTest` which currently takes up to 15 seconds until it is started and tests are executed. I already use the mocked `webEnvironment` and the `standaloneSetup()` of the specific `RestController` class.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import static org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = MOCK)
public class DataControllerMvcTests {

    @Autowired
    private DataService dataService;

    @Autowired
    private DataController dataController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(dataController)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "READ_DATA")
    public void readData() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/data")).andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
    }
}
```

Is there any other configuration I should use in order to speed it up? I use Spring Boot 1.5.9.

Comment: depending on how you break up your configurations you can additionally set the `classes` param on the `SpringBootTest` and it will only load that specific configuration. As alltej mentioned you should check out the Slice Tests, there are quite a few. However be aware that it will load _everything_ on the `SpringBootApplication` class e.g. any beans, `Enables...` etc. Ideally these should be in their own configurations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are testing a particular controller. So you can be more granular by using the `@WebMvcTest` annotation instead of the general test annotation `@SpringBootTest`. It will be much faster as it will only load a slice of your app.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = DataController.class)
public class DataControllerMvcTests {

    @Mock
    private DataService dataService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(dataController)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void readData() throws Exception {
        //arrange mock data
        //given( dataService.getSomething( "param1") ).willReturn( someData );

        mockMvc.perform(get("/data")).andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to specify an additional `Configuration` class with `WebMvcTest` where I could create a `Bean` instead of mocking it? In your example, `DataService` can't be loaded as it's a `Service` rather than a `Controller`. I know in the sliced-case scenario, we should use mocked `Service` layers but with just one more `Bean` I could test the `Service` in the same test step.